# Image in not repainting from List<path>

Tags: java, swing

i am trying to load image from specified path, and list of files are stored inside List<>.
at first time when i initialize image it display but when i am trying to display next image from **List instance which contain list of files**, it **doesn't repaint the image**.
what's wrong going is i am initializing image in constructor first time that **overwrite**
the new image, now ***where to initialize image first time outside constructor*** i don't know.

my code :

```
 public void nextImage(int cnt)
    {                   
        System.out.println(cnt);

        if (cnt < imageFiles.size()) 
        {
            System.out.println(imageFiles.size());
            try 
            {                   
                bg = ImageIO.read(new File((imageFiles.get(cnt)).toString()));

                scaled = getScaledInstanceToFit(bg, new Dimension(600, 600));
                setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            } 
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
        addMouseListener(handler);
        addMouseMotionListener(handler);           
        System.out.println(cnt);            
        System.out.println(imageFiles.get(cnt).toString());         
    }
```

menu item click code :

```
JMenuItem mntmRestoreImage = new JMenuItem("Next Image");

        final ImagePane st = new ImagePane();           

        mntmRestoreImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {                       
        @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {               
               st.nextImage(k);
               k++;     
            }
        });

        mnEdit.add(mntmRestoreImage);
```

class code & constructor :

```
private BufferedImage bg;
        private BufferedImage scaled;
java.util.List<Path> imageFiles= getFilesFromDirectory(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\New folder")); 


 public ImagePane() 
        {
try 
            {
                bg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/src11.jpg"));
                scaled = getScaledInstanceToFit(bg, new Dimension(600, 600));
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

> counter also increments, now the code inside ImagePane() constructor
>   overwrites the image of nextImage() function, so idea what happen out
>   ***in this code ??***
>
> any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you get some errors/exceptions? Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `imageFiles.get(counter).toFile()`?

Comment: Could you add the exception stack trace?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - sir i have tried imageFiles.get(counter).toFile() but its not working.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Sir imageFiles.get(counter).toString() works but the problem is that counter is not incremented. i have write all this code on menuitem click actionlistener.

Comment: Sir, will you help me that why counter is not incrementing ? what's the problem in code ?

Comment: Every time the `nextImage()` is called, you are filling the `List` with all files again and again, even though you wanted to perform this task only once, and iterate over each image, while executing this function, simply call `getFilesFromDirectory` outside this function and set `counter` to zero at that location. Moreover, why not use `bg = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read((imageFiles.get(counter++)).toFile()));`, it was my mistake that I used `toString()` in my sample example, instead of `toFile()`, though you should have given a fair thought to what @MadProgrammer has to say, about this.

Comment: What exactly is missing in this [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/75h5u9effv6ph6r/LoadImageFromDirectory.java), I posted before in comments to your previous question ?

Comment: @nIcEcOw - sir i am most near to complete this one, now counter increments, i pass counter in nextImage(cnt) call & that is incremented in each menu item click. i have got a problem that i have to define **bg** in constructor, it defined but whenever constructor calls new incremented **bg** image doesn't loaded in **bg**. each time constructor image load code overwrites nextImage() code of loading an image. any idea where to define **bg** first time and it will not occur in code execution again ???

Comment: @user2659972 : Initialize `bg` inside the `nextImage(...)` method, instead of inside the constructor. Simply create `counter` as an instance variable, instead of a local variable, and let it increment inside the `nextImage()` method alone. And simply assign `counter = 0`, where ever you are calling `getFilesFromDirectory(...)`.

Comment: @nIcEcOw - it will never work because i have to initialize bg before 'nextImage()' calls. i am asking that where can i put that code outside constructor and `nextImage()` if i put that code inside then it will overwrite image everytime.

Comment: @nIcEcOw -is there other way to initialize `bg` outside constructor ?

Comment: @user2659972 : For that I need to see the whole code, to make a valid assumption, regarding the flow of the program :-)

Comment: @nicEcOw - if you want whole code or project then i can send you.

Comment: @user2659972 : Please post it on some site then. Will try my best to have a look :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35435/discussion-between-user2659972-and-nice-cow)

Comment: @nIcEcOw - I have solved that problem, by the use of below answer of 'Gerret'. He told me to use Stack for image load from specific path and i can now choose specific directory using JFileChooser and also change Image On Button Click, thank to you also man. but now as you told me i have to rebuild whole application from start. but anyway i will try this time that code will never goes too complex to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have the perfect solution for you! I wrote a little program for you so it is easier to understand.

First I have a method for you to check if the file is a picture:

```
public Stack<File> getFilesInFolder(String startPath) {
    File startFolder = new File(startPath);
    Stack<File> picturestack = new Stack<File>();

    String extension;
    int dotindex;

    // Go through the folder
    for (File file : startFolder.listFiles()) {
        extension = "";
        dotindex = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.'); // Get the index of the dot in the filename

        if (dotindex > 0) {
            extension = file.getName().substring(dotindex + 1);

            // Iterate all valid file types and check it
            for (String filetype : validpicturetypes) {
                if (extension.equals(filetype)) {
                    picturestack.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return picturestack;
}
```

Very easy! Take the folder and iterate his files. Take the extension of the file and check if it is a valid file type. Define the file types in a array at the begining of your code.

```
String[] validpicturetypes = {"png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"};
```

At the end I push every file into a stack. Remember to fill the stack into a variable, do not read the files more than once because than you get the same problem as before:

```
Stack<File> pictures = getFilesInFolder("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop");
```

After that use a Action for your JMenuItem! In my example I do not have much, you have to put your methods in!

```
Action nextpictureaction = new AbstractAction("Next Picture") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2421742449531785343L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!pictures.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(pictures.pop().getName());
        }
    }
};
```

Add the Action at your JMenu and set the properties of your Frame.

```
/*
 * Add Components to Frame
 */
setJMenuBar(menubar);
menubar.add(toolsmenu);
toolsmenu.add(nextpictureaction);

/*
 * Frame Properties
 */
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationByPlatform(true);
setSize(1000, 700);
setTitle("PictureEditor");
setVisible(true);
```

At the end execute your program with the invokeLater method!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new PictureEditor();
        }
    });
}
```

### Summary

*Basically you need a somthing to iterate through because values like integer are not saved the way you like. In my example I used a Stack and save at the beginning all pictures in it. Important is that, if you used or finished with the picture, you have to remove it (use stack.pop() for a Stack). I do not found a method where you check if the file is a picture (if it is the ImageIO catch it is bad). I wrote a method for that if you want you could use it.*

Comment: but sir, all code is put on menuitem click, if i will put it in for loop then all data will be loaded at a time, i want to load image on each item click. for that what you say can i put break inside it ??

Comment: No than is my answer wrong I dident get your question! I ask you somthing at the chat you invent me but u left it ^^

Comment: ya sorry, broadband connection problem. that's why, so if you have any idea about that what now i have to do ?? i am just confused that now what to do ??

Comment: I updated now my answer I think I know now what you want to do

Comment: sorry sir i am not exactly getting it, if you don't mine will you tell me where i will have to write that code ? where i will have to call nextImage() function ? and what to do, i am just confused. hope you understand.

Comment: Yes I understand you I dont know now where you put that method you posted. What I would you suggest is to remove that method and make a AbstractAction like so as i descriped it. You should put that Action at you JFrame Class and a Global Integer. Basically you add that same thing from your old method to the action. I hope you understood what I mean ^^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35364/discussion-between-user2659972-and-gerret)

Comment: So forget everything I said it is wrong. I updated my answar now. If you do it like this it should work!!

Comment: @ Gerret - sir i am most near to complete this one, now **counter** increments, i pass counter in `nextImage(cnt)` call & that is incremented in each menu item click. i have got a problem that i have to define **bg** in constructor, it defined but whenever constructor calls new incremented bg image doesn't loaded in **bg**. each time constructor image load code overwrites `nextImage()` code of loading an image. any idea where to define **bg** first time and it will not occur in code execution again ???

Comment: Yes it is actully the same as the integer if I understand you right. This code I wrote works perfect. You get all pictures of your folder in a stack and you are able to get it with stack.pop() (removes it) or stack.get(int index) (if you need). Directly use the file of the stack and but it into your Buffer of whatever you use. Thats the easiest way ^^

Comment: sir everything is perfect in my code also. problem is that image must be loaded first time when application starts i have write image load code in constructor, so image loads but when i am calling nextImage() function is doesn't change the image because constructor image overwrites each time new image. so my question is, is there any way so image loaded 1st time and never comes in execution again except constructor ?

Comment: ya right, that's the problem which i am facing. any idea so that first time image loads then after our specified image will be loaded ??

Comment: Could you join the chat becuase the the discussions gets too long

Comment: Hey i have made it man, thank you so much. i have used stack concept i have solved that problem, now i have to rebuild whole application from start. thanx brother, i means a lot to me. thank you thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome :) I am glad to hear that :D I ve fun help other people ^^

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer**, but I cannot paste that much code into a comment.

I would change your code to something along the lines of this piece of code. This seperates the image loading from the gui updating logic (like adding mousehandlers and the like, I pasted only image loading code).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageLoader
{
    public static class ImageContainer
    {
        BufferedImage bg = null;

        BufferedImage scaled;
    }

    Iterator<File> imageFiles = Arrays.asList(
            new File("D:\\New folder").listFiles()).iterator();

    public ImageContainer nextImage(Dimension dimensionToFit) throws Exception
    {
        ImageContainer c = new ImageContainer();
        if (imageFiles.hasNext())
        {
                File file = imageFiles.next();
                                    //you might not need this, if only images are in this directory
                if(file.isDirectory())
                    return null;
                c.bg = ImageIO.read(file);
                c.scaled = getScaledInstanceToFit(c.bg, dimensionToFit);
                return c;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    private BufferedImage getScaledInstanceToFit(BufferedImage bg,
            Dimension dimensionToFit)
    {
        //do the risizing
    }
}
```

This is not yet optimized though.

Comment: Why would you post something in the answer section, that you, yourself have stated is **not an answer**?

Comment: @Chris: Why would you write such a comment when you did not even read the **next few words** after "This is not an answer"? Also to answer your question: I thought I could add some hints to how this code could be improved without giving a direct answer to the question, which is in daily developer business quite often the best thing one can do. To this goal, my post had to be detailed enough to add any value, which ruled out writing a comment.

Comment: Comments are of course there to add value to a question. Answers are there to, surprisingly enough, answer it. Or provide a framework designed for OP to achieve said answer. However, if you want to be arsey about it, you're kind of stuck. Either you posted an answer (in which case the bold letters are pointless) or you didn't post an answer (in which case it shouldn't have been there in the first place).