# How to set position of JSlider in window?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jslider

i am trying to put JSlider at bottom of application but it doesn't work. JSlider actually works, display everything, i just have to set it in bottom that only remain.

if anyone knows it then suggest me what i will have to do ?

my code :

```
       final JSlider slider1 ;
       slider1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,0,5,1);//direction , min , max , current

       slider1.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
       slider1.setMinorTickSpacing(25);
       slider1.setPaintLabels(true);
       slider1.setPaintTicks(true);
       slider1.setPaintTrack(true);
       slider1.setAutoscrolls(true);

       slider1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,50));
       add(slider1);
       slider1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() 
       {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fval=slider1.getValue();
            repaint();
        }
       });
```

any suggestion please...

Comment: Depends completely on the used layout manager. What are you using?

Comment: In that case, see the answer by @Gerret.

Comment: its not working, i have also used image with it.

Comment: Please be specific. What do you mean by "not working"? Is it displayed at a wrong position? If so, what is wrong about it compared to the desired result?

Comment: it's not working in the sense that it doesn't set slider at bottom otherwise everything is ok. i am displaying image also as slide state changed the brightness of image also change and parallely new image also write on disk. i just need to place slider at bottom.

Comment: Didn't you read the comment? *If so, what is wrong about it compared to the desired result?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your JSlider at the bottom try this:

```
frame.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

at your code I think it is enough if you add to

```
add(slider1);
```

this:

```
add(slider1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

EDIT:
To display a set of slider on a JFrame with your picture, add your picture at a JPanel and your slider to a JPanel. So it is easier to place it.

Than you could use:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 1, 0);
panel.add(slider1);
panel.add(slider2);
...
add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(picturepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

[All kinds of Layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

If you need more precision use a grid Layout!

Comment: It's not working, i have tried this. i am also displaying image on that window, as user slide Brightness of image will change, all done just i have to do is to set slider at botton. at each statechanged of slider i am repaint.

Comment: okok so you have to set every panel and so on at the right postion with BorderLayout. For example you have a panel with your picture. Use: add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER) and so on. If you have more slider you should put them into a other panel so you are able to set the panel at the right position. For example: JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 1, 0)); panel.add(slider); With the grid Layout you are able to put your compnents at a grid. I update my answer a little bit ^^

Comment: yes it is, i have put both part in different panel and then separated them in screen region i.e. CENTER and SOUTH, thank you so much.

Comment: if you don't mine will you help me last time, my whole application is ready, 1 thing just remaining that i can't understand what problem in that. my question is [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202788/image-in-not-loaded-from-listpath

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35354/discussion-between-user2659972-and-gerret)